# Django: How can I store in database a variable which I generate in a random function?

Tags: python, django, random

My web application is in django and it displays random images every time the user press the 'next' button. I try to store the name or better the number of the image which is concatenated on its name. For example, if the name is 'image4.jpg' then I want to store the number 4 as number or as text.

So, first I have a class in the models.py file.

```
class Session(User):
    image_number = models.IntegerField()
```

The type of the variable is probably wrong because I don't want to get this from a form. I generate the number in the views.py file. So, I just want to store it.

As I said I have a function in the views.py file which generates the random numbers.

```
def func_random(self):
    random_im_list = random.sample(xrange(1,20),5)
    return {1v: random_im_list[0],
            2v: random_im_list[1],
            ... etc}
```

So, here I generate a list of 5 numbers, because I want to display 5 images in every session. The user presses 5 times the 'next' button and each time he can see a new random image.

I have also in views.py five classes  for the five Pages.

```
class Image1(Page):

class Image2(Page):

class Image3(Page):

class Image4(Page):

class Image5(Page):
```

Here I need some help because I don't wait any input from the user. I already have generated the list with the random numbers. So, how can I store them on the database? 
The database after the first session must have 5 columns with one number in each column.

And after that I have the template file:

```
    {% if Page == 1 %}

        <div>
             <im src="{{static_url}}images/image{{ 1v }}.jpg" />   
        <div>
    {% elif Page == 2 %}
        <div>
             <im src="{{static_url}}images/image{{ 2v }}.jpg" />   
        <div>

etc....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make more sense for you to have a single view that takes the image number as an argument. You can then check to see if it's the first image, and if so, generate a list of random images for the user to see. Also, you should consider using [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) for what you're trying to do. If you use sessions, you could write your view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def image_view(request, image_number): # image_number is from 1 to 5
    if image_number == 1:
        request.session['image_list'] = list(random.sample(xrange(1,20),5))
    image = request.session['image_list'][image_number - 1]
    return render(request, "yourtemplate.html", {"image_number": image_number, "image": image})
```

Your template could look something like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="{{static_url}}images/image{{ image }}.jpg" />
</div>
```

And in your URL configuration, make sure to write it like this so that your view is properly parameterized by the image number:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^images/([1-5])/$', views.image_view),
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. If I don't want to use sessions, which is the type for the variable in the models.py file. I am noob in django and I don't understand it very well. When you create a class in the models.py file, the attributes of this class become columns on the database, right?

Comment: You could use a [CommaSeparatedIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield). Then the image numbers would be stored like "5,7,1,14,11", so you'd have to put them into a string.

Comment: You could also use [django-picklefield](https://github.com/gintas/django-picklefield), which can store python objects directly into the database